# How to include report generation date in javadoc footer when using maven 3?

Tags: maven, report, javadoc

How - using `org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-javadoc-plugin` - can I get the footer or bottom to include the date/time that the Javadocs report was written?

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html lists the options, including footer or bottom, but does not show how to include "today's date" in the report.

Comment: Well, you can specify header and footer parameters and set them to contain `${maven.build.timestamp}` property value.

Comment: Thanks's Andrew: that's worked a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All credit goes to [Andrew Logvinov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/966590/andrew-logvinov) for this :-)

In your pom, add something like the following to /project/properties:

```
<maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm z</maven.build.timestamp.format>
```

In your javadoc plugin add something like the following footer configuration option:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <stylesheet>maven</stylesheet>
        <footer>Generated ${maven.build.timestamp}</footer>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```